# Convert number to date in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, numbers

I have different numbers looking like 40825 and I want to convert them to an actual date in Oracle SQL.

I know it should be `SELECT TO_DATE(40825 ,'MM-DD-YYYY')` in SQL Server, but this does not work with the same syntax in oracle SQL.

Any help?

Comment: Just found the solution:

SELECT
      TO_CHAR ( TO_DATE ( '1900-01-01',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD' )
              + 40825,
              'DD/MON/YYYY' )
FROM
      DUAL

Comment: exactly what does `40825` represent? minutes? seconds? millicenturies? days?

Comment: It was considered to be days.

Comment: @Louwinho . . . You should delete the question if you are no longer looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

If this number mean 4 day, 8 month, and year 2025 then, u must use to_date function with string (not nubmer) and string must looks like date mask.

```
SELECT TO_DATE(to_char(40825,'FM000000')  ,'MMDDYY') FROM dual
```